# Regression analysis of facets using seaborn's relplot

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression, facet-grid

I am still fairly new to seaborn so please bear with me. I am trying to do a linear least squares regression and specify the r^2 value using seaborn's relplot. I am open to switching to just sns.facetgrid. My data looks like:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFiaK.png)

I am able to plot the facet grids as: [Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlwnJ.png)

My code to generate such a plot looks like:

```
xx = np.linspace(-1, 2, 100)
yx = xx 

#CO2 vs H 

p1 = sns.relplot(data=df2, x="H", y="CO2", col="Bias", hue="Met", col_wrap=5)
(p1.set_axis_labels("$E_{ads}(*H)$", "$E_{ads}(*CO_2)$")
  .set_titles("Bias: {col_name} V vs SHE")
  .set(xlim=(-0.4, 2), ylim=(-0.4, 2)))

for ax in p1.axes.flat: 
       ax.plot(xx, yx)

plt.savefig("CO2_H.pdf", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

However, instead of a diagonal line I would like it to be a linear regression. I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175006/regression-line-using-relplot-in-seaborn), but I can't figure out how to get this to work when you specify the columns in sns.relplot.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know whether seaborn has any ability perform linear regression, never tried it, but I'd suggest simply using `sklearn.linear_model.LinerarRegression ` to calculate coefficients of your regression line and then plot it as normal. Or, alternatively, use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` to calculate least-squares regression.

Comment: You are using `hue=` nesting. Do you expect one regression per hue level?

Comment: No, I would like one regression per bias. So in the image shown above there is one data point for each hue level (5 total) at each bias, so I would like to perform a regression on those 5 points at each bias (of which there are also 5). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into `seaborn.lmplot`.

```
p1 = sns.lmplot(data=df2, x="H", y="CO2", col="Bias", hue="Met", col_wrap=5)
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html